# Reloading bind entity cause "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This has been asked before, but none of the available answers seem to fit to my case.
In order to perform some validation, I have to reload from DB the same entity, which already bound to the model. The following causes the error. I'm almost losing my mind.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Tekes tekes, FormCollection fc)
{
  ...
  Tekes myTekes = db.Tkasim.Find(tekes.TeksID);
  <some validation here>
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     db.Entry(tekes).State = EntityState.Modified;
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = tekes.TekesID });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you have to grab the same entity from the data base. Anyway, the problem is that the `Find` statement adds the `Tekes` object to the context, subsequently the statement `db.Entry(tekes).State = EntityState.Modified` tries to do the same. It's not clear what the validation is all about, but I think you can solve this by replacing the `Find` by

```
var myTekes = db.Tkasim.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.TeksId == tekes.TeksID);
```

[AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) tells EF to fetch entities without adding them to the cache and the state manager.